# Generate a table with <divs> where each row should contains same set of html elements but with unique id's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using a table which is made using div tags where each div tag is assigned to `row` class. Each and every row is containing a checkbox, two dropdowns, quantity spinner and a button. For now, I have hard-coded these rows for five times as each and every element in a row have to have a unique id. But I need to automate these row creation and appending according to a count I am getting from the database records. I have got the record count using ajax function as well. I have gone through some of the posts but all of them are about populating and appending a same row with same set of elements in the row have no unique ids.

This is my code in jsp;

```
<div class="row item-tbl-row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <form:checkbox value="pizza" class="checkbox chkbxPkgCat" path="categoryName" id="chkPkgPzza" />Pizza
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <form:select type="text" class="form-control" path="itemName" id="slctItmPkgPzza">
      <form:option value="-" label="---" />
    </form:select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <form:select type="text" class="form-control" path="" id="szpr1">
      <form:option value="-" label="---" />
    </form:select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <input class="qty-spinner" type="number" min="0" id="pzzaQty" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <form:button type="button" value="" class="btn btn-success btnAddItmPkg" id="btnAddPkgPizza">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add
    </form:button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row item-tbl-row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <form:checkbox value="Salad" class="checkbox chkbxPkgCat" path="" id="chkPkgSld" />Salad
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <form:select type="text" class="form-control" path="itemName" id="slctItmPkgSalad">
      <form:option value="-" label="---" />
    </form:select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <form:select type="text" class="form-control" path="" id="szprc2">
      <form:option value="-" label="---" />
    </form:select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <input class="qty-spinner" type="number" id="sldQty" min="0" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <form:button type="button" value="" class="btn btn-success btnAddItmPkg" id="btnAddPkgSalad">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add
    </form:button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using these ids for extracting and sending the values for processing purposes as follows and want to send them as json data . And that is why I am in need of populating the elements with unique ids.

```
 /*
     * populating the item list in add Package.jsp
     **/
    $(".chkbxPkgCat").click(function () {
        var categoryNm = $(this).val();
        var slctElement = $(this).parent().parent().next().find(".form-control").attr('id');
        var selectedItm = $(this).parent().parent().next().next().find(".form-control").attr('id');

        setItemList(categoryNm, slctElement, selectedItm);
    });
```

How can I generate this table using jQuery and javascript where the elements of the rows can have unique ids? Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: use class instead of id?? Really not clear what you are asking or trying to accomplish

Comment: @charlietfl I need to make table using divs. Each div is acting as a row. That row is consisting 4 elements as a checkbox, two drop-downs and a button. Those elements should have unique id. And I want to generate this row with those elements along five times. But I have no idea how append them with uniqe ids. So I want to know whether there is a way to do so or else how can I auto generate this table using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create one row and then you can clone it changing generating new ids for each clone

```js
var n = 5;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  $('.row:first').clone().after("#id")
    .appendTo(document.body)
    .find('.checkbox').text('Text' + i).end()
    .find('*[id]').each(function() {
      $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + i)
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row item-tbl-row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <form:checkbox value="pizza" class="checkbox chkbxPkgCat" path="categoryName" id="chkPkgPzza" />Pizza
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <form:select type="text" class="form-control" path="itemName" id="slctItmPkgPzza">
      <form:option value="-" label="---" />
    </form:select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <form:select type="text" class="form-control" path="" id="szpr1">
      <form:option value="-" label="---" />
    </form:select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <input class="qty-spinner" type="number" min="0" id="pzzaQty" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <form:button type="button" value="" class="btn btn-success btnAddItmPkg" id="btnAddPkgPizza">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add
    </form:button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ! It really worked finely. I made some modifications  accordingly for my purpose. Thanks again I learned some new things. :)

Comment: You could add this to the css: `.row:first-of-type {display: none}`

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is just to get a unique id then you could generate an id with a function like

```js
function createID() {
  return "id-" + Date.now();
}
console.log(createID());
```

and assign the id like `$(elmt).attr('id', createID());` every time you append a new elmt.